# Updating class field from callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to connect to API using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). I need to login user and after this set `"user"` field which contains session key which is required to all other api calls. So I need to have it available before executing any code but I don't know how to check or block code until this field will be set. Any ideas how to do it?

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String developerKey = "";
public static final String applicationKey = "";

static final String BASE_URL =
        "https://secure.techfortesco.com/tescolabsapi";

public ApiService mApiService;
public User user;

public ApiClient() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel( RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL )
            .setEndpoint( BASE_URL )
            .build();

    if(mApiService == null) {
        mApiService = restAdapter.create( ApiService.class );
    }
}

public void login() {

    mApiService.login( developerKey, applicationKey, new Callback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void success ( User user, Response response ) {
            //code which should update user field
        }

        @Override
        public  void failure ( RetrofitError error ) {

        }

    } );
}

public interface ApiService {

    @GET ("/restservice.aspx?command=LOGIN&email=&password=")
    public void login (
            @Query ("developerkey") String developerKey,
            @Query ("applicationkey") String applicationKey,
            Callback<User> callback );

    @GET ("/restservice.aspx?command=PRODUCTSEARCH")
    public void search (
            @Query ("searchtext") String searchText,
            @Query ("sessionkey") String sessionKey,
            Callback<Pojo.SearchResult> callback);
}
}
```

Comment: It really depends of your usage. Who is calling login and when you suppouse to call another request in the Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using callback:

Example:

```
public interface LoginCallback {
    void ready();
}
```

And in the Activity / Fragment

```
public MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ApiClient client = new ApiClient();
        client.login(new LoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void ready() {
            //... do your next request in the API.
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

and your login method became:

```
public void login(final LoginCallback loginCallback) {

 mApiService.login( developerKey, applicationKey, new Callback<User>() {

    @Override
    public void success ( User user, Response response ) {
        //code which should update user field
        loginCallback.ready();
    }

    @Override
    public  void failure ( RetrofitError error ) {

    }

} );
```

}